# Why does Jquery AJAX appends empty table cells on top of cells containing data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ajaxq

So I am using AJAX via jquery to append data to a table after someone clicks on the submit button , IT works , but the thing is that it first appends two horizontal table cells that are empty , then gets followed by the cells containing data and as long as I click on the submit button , those empty cells add up , it looks weird .. is there a way to fix this .. Below is my code .

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$( document ).on( 'click', '#submit_button', function () {
  event.preventDefault();

  var sku = $("#sku").val(); 
  var dec = $("#dec").val(); 


     $.ajax({
        url:"check_sku.php", 
         data:{sku: sku, dec:dec}, 
         type:"POST", 
        success:function(result){

            if(result !="MEID / DEC / SIM needed"){   
              $(".rows").remove();
              $("#submit_button").remove();
              $("#cancel").remove();
              $("#enter_product_sku").remove();
              $("#table_1").append(result);
            }
              if(result =="MEID / DEC / SIM needed"){          

                  $("#meid").show();

              }               
        }

      });


    });

});
```

The data that gets appended , contained in the result variable is this ... any reason why it adds a row of two empty table cells first ?

```
<tr class ='rows'><td style ='background:#CC9900;font-weight:bold;'>$title</td><td style='font-weight:bold;'>$count</td></tr>
    <tr id ="enter_product_sku"><td> Enter the product SKU </td><td><input id ="sku" type="text" name ="sku[]" size="20" value ="" /> </td></tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
        <input id ="submit_button"  class ="career_activation" style ="background:#33CC66; width:70px;  height: 50px; color:white; font-weight:bold;padding:10px;" type ="submit" name="submit" value ="ADD" /></td>
        <td>
        <input id ="cancel"  class ="career_activation" style ="background:#CC0000; width:70px; height: 50px; color:white; font-weight:bold; padding:10px;"type ="reset" name="cancal" value ="CANCEL" /></td>
        </tr>
```

console log string

```
 <tr class ='rows'><td style ='background:#CC9900;font-weight:bold;'>Charger2</td><td style='font-weight:bold;'>18</td></tr><tr class ='rows'><td style ='background:#CC9900;font-weight:bold;'>Charger</td><td style='font-weight:bold;'>4</td></tr><tr class ='rows'><td style ='background:#CC9900;font-weight:bold;'>Iphone 6</td><td style='font-weight:bold;'>3</td></tr><tr class ='rows'><td style ='background:#CC9900;font-weight:bold;'>Previal</td><td style='font-weight:bold;'>4</td></tr><tr id ="enter_product_sku"><td> Enter the product SKU </td><td><input id ="sku" type="text" name ="sku[]" size="20" value ="" /> </td></tr><tr>
<td>
<input id ="submit_button"  class ="career_activation" style ="background:#33CC66; width:70px;  height: 50px; color:white; font-weight:bold;padding:10px;" type ="submit" name="submit" value ="ADD" /></td>
<td>
<input id ="cancel"  class ="career_activation" style ="background:#CC0000; width:70px; height: 50px; color:white; font-weight:bold; padding:10px;"type ="reset" name="cancal" value ="CANCEL" /></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: please consider using a else statement instead of the second if statement as well as === type comparison if you always compare strings

Comment: @Bill'o  ok .. so WHY are empty cells appended ?? that is my question

Comment: seeing the few lines of code, the result string must be wrong, could you log it in the console and show it to us?

Comment: @Bill'o  I added the console log string ... and it doesn't contain the two empty table cells ..

Comment: could you provide the initial html markup of the table?

Comment: You want your jQuery selector to target the last table row in the table, not the table itself...try something like 
$('#table_1 tr:last').after('your html here');

Comment: It doesn't add empty cells. Those cells are existing cells that are not remove with the AJAX success function that remove their content such as the submit button leaving them empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax(
{
    url:"check_sku.php", 
    data:{sku: sku, dec:dec}, 
    type:"POST", 
    success:
        function(result)
        {
            if(result !="MEID / DEC / SIM needed")
            {   
                $(".rows").remove();
                $("#submit_button").remove();//does not remove the tr and td tags only the input thus the remaining empty tds and trs
                $("#cancel").remove();//Same here
                $("#enter_product_sku").remove();//and here
                $("#table_1").append(result);
            }
            else if(result =="MEID / DEC / SIM needed")//I also added @Bill'o comments
            {
                $("#meid").show();
            }               
        }

    }
);
```

See explainations in code

Consider this maybe:

```
$.ajax(
{
    url:"check_sku.php", 
    data:{sku: sku, dec:dec}, 
    type:"POST", 
    success:
        function(result)
        {
            if(result !="MEID / DEC / SIM needed")
            {   
                $(".rows").remove();
                $("#submit_button").parent().parent().remove();
                $("#enter_product_sku").remove();
                $("#table_1").append(result);
            }
            else if(result =="MEID / DEC / SIM needed")//I also added @Bill'o comments
            {
                $("#meid").show();
            }               
        }

    }
);
```

You could also remove every tr before inserting the results.

Comment: Thank you .. that fixed it .. Sebastien , t'es francais ?

Comment: Nope, Canadien Français